# Can I send ALL my Ether to a Payable function? or should a little be saved to pay for Gas?

Tags: gas, contract-invocation, gas-estimate, payable

I have this big doubt about how the EVM works,

Let's say I have an Ether balance of **1000000000000000000** in Wei (1 Ether) and I want to pass ALL of it to a payable function, let's call the function buy():

```
Contract.buy({ from: '0x0...', value: 1000000000000000000 });
```

**Will that work? meaning; Will that in itself deduct GAS costs?**

Or, on the contrary... I have to estimate Gas cost and deduct it myself from the Ether I'm sending? for example, If I estimate 50000 in Gas, I'd do it like this:

```
Contract.buy({ from: '0x0...', value: 999999999999950080, gas: 50000 });
```

Which approach is the correct one and Why?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT (Code in Swift):

```
    var options = Veev.options(gas: nil, from: addressFrom)
    let contract = web3.contract(contractABI, at: EthereumAddress(Rinkeby.address))
    let parameters = [EthereumAddress("0x0.."), amountToBuy] as [AnyObject]
    guard let estimatedGas = web3.contract(contractABI, at: EthereumAddress(Rinkeby.address))?.method("buy", parameters: parameters, options: options)?.estimateGas(options: nil) else { return }
    options.gas = estimatedGas
    let value: BigUInt = BigUInt(ether) - BigUInt(estimatedGas) * BigUInt(5000000000) - 1 // 5000000000 is gas Price
    options.value = value
```

Comment: updated ans check. You can transfer all eth by specifying gasPrice 0.

Comment: Thanks, do explain. If I set gasPrice to 0, do I still have to use this formula:
1 ether - 55000 * 1 gwei?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latter. The total ether required to make a transaction is `amount + gasLimit * gasPrice` (`amount` being how much ether you're sending). So you need to set aside enough ether to cover the maximum the transaction may cost for gas.

In your example of needing 50000 in gas, you'd want to send, say, `1 ether - 50000 * 1 gwei` and specify a 1 gwei gas price.

Comment: Thank you very much! I really needed to hear commentary from a pro.

Comment: I have tried very hard to put this into code, but I'm still getting the following error: "insufficient funds for gas * price + value". It seems it's a more or less 'common' error, Any ideas about what I'm doing wrong, sir? Thanks.

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: Sure, but it's in Swift. However there's an update: I managed to make it work by using this formula: ether - estimatedGas * gasPrice, the only difference to the formula you gave then would be 5 gwei instead of the 1 gwei. 5 gwei (5000000000) seems to be default gas price in my case, what do you think?

Comment: Just added some sample code, hope it's self-explanatory, it's essentially the same (hopefully!)

Comment: You're the one who picks the gas price, but I don't see anywhere in your code where you're specifying it.

Comment: Perhaps you're leaving it unspecified and letting something else choose, but you'll definitely need to know what gas price is going to be used so you can do the calculation properly.

Comment: Yes, it's 5000000000 by default. I can of course change it, but I chose not to because I read that lowering its value may cause delays in the transaction processing times. Considering this default, what's the best formula to use then? Thanks

Comment: 1 gwei is _plenty_ right now, but in times of heavy traffic, you'll need as much as 30 or 40 gwei to get a transaction through. https://ethgasstation.info/ is a good way to see what an appropriate gas price is.

Comment: Thank you, I'd appreciate it more than anything, If you could please tell me what's the definitive formula I need. Is this one correct: ether - estimatedGas * gasPrice ... Or should I change something?

Comment: I'd phrase it as `balance - gasLimit * gasPrice`, but yes. (You're setting the gas limit according to the estimated gas, which is an appropriate thing to do.)

Comment: Sadly, for some weird reason the formula sometimes works, sometimes does not.

Comment: Are you 100% sure the gas price is always being set to the same amount? I would explicitly specify it to make sure.

Comment: It worked again, but I will have to perform several tests in order to make sure the formula is right

Answer (score 1):

> Can I send ALL my Ether to a Payable function? or should a little be
>   saved to pay for Gas?

Yes you can, by setting gasPrice is 0. But in real time we don't know how much time it will take to execute, It depends on situation. I seen in etherscan some of the transaction's value is 0.

Refer following link for the same:
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x173fd250d63a62bb407f214ff924b49e1c90593572eab1a8c523783f2aa58ba3

In your example of you can estimate gas for buy() function using `Contract. buy.estimateGas({ from: '0x0...', value: 1000000000000000000})` will tell how much gas will consume for a method. So no need to assume, but some dev's are complaining its not returning accurate value. Better to add 5-10% extra value.

Thats for safer side in above method lets assume its your estimated 55000 gas for  exec buy(), then you need to send value to method is `1 ether - 55000 * 1 gwei`

Comment: Thank you very much, using the formula above (let's say it's 3ETH): 
3 ether - 80000 * 1 gwei, I'm getting the following error: "insufficient funds for gas * price + value" (My estimated Gas is 72000 and I round it up 80000). Any idea How to fix it?